# Http Exception error responding to incoming calls (TWILIO)

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm following the responding to incoming calls in C# on the Twilio website 
(https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-in-csharp) yet when executing the code (using xamarin studio IDE on mac) and using th input for the ngrok tunnel as listed in th tutorial I'm getting a "system.web.http exception".

anyone know what i may be doing wrong?

**Stack Trace**: at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) [0x0003d] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String controllerName) [0x0003c] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.Web.Mvc.IController& controller, System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory& factory) [0x00066] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00012] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext httpContext, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00007] in :0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object extraData) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x00d9c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1335 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:927

**Code**:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.TwiML.Mvc;

public class VoiceController : TwilioController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Say("hello world!", voice: "alice");

        return TwiML(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You managed to post everything that is not related to the question but forgot what is actually relevant. Please add the stacktrace and code.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'd love to help out, but as the previous commenter said, we need to see the code and the stack trace in order to try to help. If you can edit your question with those details and then drop a comment here to notify me, that'd be great!

Comment: Hey phil - I added the code. To further explain my issue, When I enter the code into my IDE, "twilio.Twiml.MVC" causes an error. I'm also attempting to use macOS Server to host this test app using ngrok for tunneling @philnash